# Customize form rendering {{ form(form)}} vs. {{ form_widget(form) }} in TWIG

Tags: forms, symfony, widget, twig

I am trying to customize form rendering in Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). I manage to customize the "text" widgets but fail to customize the "submit" widget. I have been debugging this issue in numerous ways and came out to the following (more simple) roadblock:

My controller is very standard and looks like this:

```
$user = new user();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
->add('name','text')
//other text items...
->add('save','submit', array('label'=> 'Signup'))

$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->is Valid()) {
//render the template...
}
```

Now, if I render the form in TWIG with

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Everything works perfectly (the form gets submitted). But if I change this into:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

The "submit" button does not submit anything (which I guess means that either the button does not trigger anything or my form somehow would not be valid anymore).

Symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html seems to state that those two should render the form similarly. Could anyone give some guidance on where this issue could be coming from? Ultimately, I get the same issue when I try to use {{ form_widget(form.save) }} to customize the "submit" button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Symfony Best Practices book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html) say "Best Practice:
Add buttons in the templates, not in the form classes or the controllers."

Comment: This is helpful. I should have looked at the Best Practices that showed that I needed to add {{ form_start(form) }} and {{ form_end(form) }} for the code above to work.